# MYSQL index with text fileds

Tags: mysql

I try build an index for **article (own_a)** table because can't use the exist index.

The SELECT contain 6 fileds from article table, 3 integer, 1 varchar (30) and 2 text. If I delete 2 text filed from the query, use index succesfully. But how build index with 2 large text filed? I will get error: "Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes".

```
SELECT
                                own_a.id AS article_id,
                                own_a.article_number,
                                own_d.id AS dealer_id,
                                own_d.name AS dealer,
                                own_a.tecdoc_article_id,
                                own_a.description,
                                own_a.extra_description,
                                'art' AS type,
                                al.genart_id,
                                1 AS own
                        FROM own_db.article AS own_a
                        JOIN own_db.dealer AS own_d ON own_a.dealer_id = own_d.id

                 JOIN `common_db`.`article` AS a ON a.id = own_a.t_article_id
                 JOIN `common_db`.`article_linkage` AS al ON al.article_id = a.id
                        WHERE
                                own_a.id IS NOT NULL
                                AND 1=1
                                AND al.genart_id IN (273,251,2462,3229,1334,1080,854,919,188,1632,1626,1213,12,3845,51,191,1547,653,2070,572,654,188,854)
                                AND ( 1=0 OR a.dealer_id IN (10,101,110,134,140,156,161,192,301,316,317,32,35,55,6,85,89,9,95) )
                                AND al.type_type = 2
                                AND al.type_id = 19799
                        GROUP BY own_a.id
                        ORDER BY  own_a.id
```

explain SELECT...:

```
    id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                                           key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
    1   SIMPLE      own_a   ALL     PRIMARY,article_number,id,idx_id_an,idx_id_did,idx...   NULL    NULL    NULL    20088   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
    1   SIMPLE      al      ref     ArtId                                                   ArtId   17      commondb.own_a.t_article_id,const,con...    2   Using where
    1   SIMPLE      own_d   eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                 PRIMARY 8       own_db.own_a.dealer_id  
    1   SIMPLE      a       eq_ref  PRIMARY,dealer_id,dealer_id_index                       PRIMARY 8       own_db.own_a.t_article_id   1   Using where
```

USE INDEX (..) didn't work.

Thx for help

Comment: The query plan you posted doesn't match the query...

Comment: I want copy just important part, but fixed it

Comment: the answer is simple, unfortunately: the maximum length of an index is limited. Basically that just means you cannot sensibly use a text field as index (and i doubt there are many examples where it would make much sense in the first place)

Comment: I don't see any of the conditions (WHERE or ON) using a text field. By "use index succesfully" do you mean that the `type` in the query plan is `index`?

Comment: I don't want use the index with text field but MYSQL want. Or perhaps I don't understand the logic. Simle examle SELECT id, description from table where id = 1. Mysql sometimes not use PRIMARY index if SELECT part contain other filed(s). When I drop "description" from query..surprise, use index. Why?

Comment: It was just an example. If I drop own_a.description,
own_a.extra_description from the original query, mysql can use index. Why??? What matters is the SELECT part for the index?